# Is it possible to fight tree height limit with centrifugal force?

Tags: water, biophysics, centrifugal-force

I heard tree has some height limit because water cannot be pumped over some height (130m if I remember it right) which cap the limit of tallest tree possible on earth

But there are centrifugal force at equator. So if we could bring a tree to very high altitude is it possible that that tree will continue to grow because water could still pumped up?

Comment: Is there a purpose to this question? Is there a need to grow trees more than 130m tall?  To me this seems to be idle speculation.

Answer (score 1):

At the equator the effect on the local value of $g$ due to the rotation of the Earth and the non-spherical shape is only a few parts in a thousand.
So even planting a tree at the top of a high mountain at the Equator probably will not have much of an effect on its ultimate height.
I found this [Scientific American article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-large-trees-such-a/) interesting although it did not comment on the maximum height of a tree as a function of location.

Comment: I don't mind artificial altitude, it could be skyscraper or floating ground build around space elevator. Just wonder that if we grow general sherman around that area would it continue to grow